# C, I want to pass 3 arguments to a bash script, I am a noob in c

Tags: c, bash

I have read a little and learned a little about syestem function in c.
So, assuming I have a bash file ./some.sh that takes three arguments how should I make this code work? It will not compile with an error about the buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "/bin/bash ./some.sh %s %s %s", target1, target2, target3);
    system(buffer)
}
```

Comment: `buffer` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @wildplasser baby steps on this statically typed languages..

Comment: Please post code that compiles!

Comment: I am posting because it can not compile @EdHeal

Comment: The error messages from the compiler will tell you how to fix it. Learning this is one of the most fundamental techniques in computer programming

Comment: I had never done c before and I was looking for a quick fix to the problem, I agree with your sentiments all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly more complicated, but safer, would be to avoid `system` and explicitly call `fork` and some version of `exec` (below, I use `execl`). (Error handling omitted for simplicity.) This avoids the need to ensure that each argument is correctly quoted for creating a shell command line.

```
int main(void) {
    // ...
    if (fork() == 0) {
        execl("/bin/bash", "./some.sh", target1, target2, target3, (char *)0);
    }
}
```

(Note: the *approach* is sound; my actual C implementation may leave something to be desired.)

Answer (score 0):

You've used the `buffer` variable without actually declaring it. This works in Bash, but not in C. If you wanted `buffer` to be an array of characters, say, 1024 characters long, you could write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "/bin/bash ./some.sh %s %s %s", target1, target2, target3);
    system(buffer)
}
```

(Of course, `target1`, `target2` and `target3` have to exist as well, but I assume those are placeholder names.)

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a shot

Comment: @steve-254 BTW, don't do this in real life.

Comment: Sure, thanks, @IharobAlAsimi someone gave me the fork method.